# Global variable added to window in Jest test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, this, global

I am seeing some weird behavior in a Jest test. When I use
width = 600 below, the test passes but when I use var width = 600 instead it fails with the this.width being undefined. Both work in a real browser. Why do they behave differently? Shouldn't the var width = 600 work?

The working test is just below and the not working one is below that.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

let spy;

width = 600;
var shape = {width: 300};

var showWidth = function()
{
    document.write(this.width);
}

describe('checkSomeScopeStuff', function () {

     it('check2', () => {
     spy = jest.spyOn(document, 'write');

     showWidth();

     expect(spy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(600);
    });
});
```

---

The test that fails is:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

let spy;

var width = 600;
var shape = {width: 300};

var showWidth = function()
{
    document.write(this.width);
}

describe('checkSomeScopeStuff', function () {

     it('check2', () => {
     spy = jest.spyOn(document, 'write');

     showWidth();

     expect(spy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, `this` is referring to a global object. In the browser that is the `window` object. Declaring a variable without a keyword like `var` can result in properties in the global scope being defined or overwritten. That's what is occurring in your first example.

In your second example, `this.width` is `undefined` because, it's `undefined`. If you used `width`, it would work.

I don't think you'd see the same behavior you do in your first example if you were to run the code with `use strict`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But shouldn't it be defined in the second case due to the appearance of the var width = 600? It seems to be defined when I run in a browser with var width = 600 but not in the jest test case.

Comment: No because declaring a variable in the global scope does not mean it's attached to a global object like `window`. `this` is referencing a global object and then `.width` is attempting to reference a property on the global object, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Reason I thought so was I am looking at page 114 of the book Javascript & JQuery by Jon Duckett and it says "All global variables also become properties of the window object..." and then it gives the example I have in my test case with the var width = 600; and then accessed by way of this.width in a global function. Perhaps the behavior has changed since the book was published.

Comment: Hmm I did not know that. I bet if you changed it to `global.width = 600;` it would work since it's running in node. That is, it would work for you second example but not the first.